# How to set mysql system variables such as max_allowed_packet max_allowed_packet, character_set_server and collation-server through Dockerfile?

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I am using Docker for mysql. Need to set the system variables such as max_allowed_packet, character_set_server and collation-server of mysql in the Dockerfile. I tried with the below commands providing in the Dockerfile. but its not working.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:latest
VOLUME /opt/data:/var/lib/mysql
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD password
RUN sed -i 's/^max_allowed_packet.*/max_allowed_packet = 1073741824/' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
RUN sed -i "/\[mysqld]/a character-set-server=utf8mb4" /etc/mysql/my.cnf
RUN sed -i 's/^collation-server.*/collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci/' /etc/mysql/my.cnf 
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

Build command:

```
sudo docker build -t mysqltest:1 .
```

Run command:

```
sudo docker run -p 3306:3306 -restart=always -d mysqltest:1
```

Comment: Could you rather use the docker `COPY` or `ADD` docker command to maintain an external (local to the build) `my.cnf` file and copy it to the container's image?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several approaches, this is one:

```
CMD ["--character-set-server=utf8mb4", "--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci", "--max-allowed-packet=1073741824"]
```

---

As an alternative you can put a custom config file in `/etc/mysql/conf.d`

custom-mysql.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 1073741824
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:latest
COPY ./custom-mysql.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

More [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)